# Laravel: Create a new record in a has many relashionship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following tables

- Users

  - id
- Books

  - id
- favourite_books

  - id
  - user_id (FK)
  - book_id (FK)

In my models I have the following:

```
class User {
    public function favouriteBooks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'favourite_books');
    }
}

class Book {
    public function usersFavourited()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favourite_books');
    }
}
```

How do I create a new book that a user has favourited? In other words,what is the Laravel way in creating a new row in the `favourite_books` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Laravel documentation under many to many relationships ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships ) it shows the following:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$user->roles()->attach($roleId);
```

In your case `roles()` would be the relationship method for books on your user model (`favouriteBooks()`) and `$roleid` would be the id of the book being favourited.